# A bag contains 5 red marbles and 6 white marbles. Two marbles are drawn in succession without replacement.

Tags: probability

1. The first marble drawn is red and the second is white
2. Both marbles drawn are red.

Comment: What is giving you trouble with this question? Can you post your work so far?

Comment: What *is* this question? The probability that each one will happen, the probability that they won't? The probability that those two events will happen in succession?

Answer (score 2):

I like to go step by step with these ones. So the first turn, you have a $\frac{5}{11}$ chance of picking a red marble. But then, you only have 10 marbles left, so the probability of picking a white marble is $\frac{6}{10}$. Multiplying these yields $\frac{3}{11}$.

You can do the second with the same process.